# Linear Algebra: Proof of isomorphic V.S.'s, given the existence of 2 injective maps

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations

Prove that if $E$ and $F$ are finitely dimensional v.s.'s and if there exist two linear injections $T: E \rightarrow F$ and $S: F \rightarrow E$, then $E$ and $F$ are isomorphic.

Note: $F$ and $E$ are isomorphic if there is a bijection from one field to the other that preserves addition and scaler multiplication (i.e. $\Phi(u+v)=\Phi(u)+\Phi(v)$ and $\Phi(cv)=c\Phi(v)$).

I am having trouble proving Surjectivity of $S$ and $T$, as well as showing that the operations are preserved- because I don't have a defined function. Suggestions? Help?

Comment: Wouldn't saying $\dim(E) \leq \dim(F)$ and vice versa be enough, since two vector spaces of equal dimension are always isomorphic?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to show that $S$ and $T$ are surjective. You only need to show that there is *some* bijective linear map between $E$ and $F$. You can use, for example, that two finite-dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic iff they have the same dimension.